# OpenCart How to get store details to controller

Tags: php, opencart

I can track customer data using

```
   $this->customer->getFirstName();
   $this->customer->getLastName();
   $this->customer->getEmail();
```

this way,and is there any similar way to track store data like email, store name 
eg: like this `$this->store->getEmail();` **(this is not working)**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the following:

```
$this->config->get('config_name'); // store name
$this->config->get('config_title'); // store title
$this->config->get('config_owner'); // store owner name
$this->config->get('config_email'); // store email
```

Comment: Just a note: same for the other inputs you can find on the store settings page, e.g. `$this->config->get('config_country_id')`